# Error while importing telepot

Tags: python, import, pip, virtualenv

I'm trying to build my own bot but I've some troubles when I try to import the `telepot` package.
I installed telepot with the command to a `virtualenv`:

```
pip install telepot
```

and I've no problems when I do

```
python
import telepot
```

But to use the `GPIO` it's necessary the be the super user, so

```
sudo python
import telepot
```

but the answer is

```
ImportError: No module named telepot
```

What is wrong?

Comment: try `sudo bash` then enter python and import telepot

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Mate on a Raspberry Pi 2

Comment: I'm also using virtualenv. I followed this tutorial [link](http://www.instructables.com/id/Set-up-Telegram-Bot-on-Raspberry-Pi/?ALLSTEPS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `virtualenv` and want to execute Python with `sudo`, try this:

1. activate your virtualenv
2. `pip install telepot`
3. get the path to virtualenv's Python with `which python`
4. deactivate virtualenv
5. execute `sudo <path_to_python_from_step3>`
6. `import telepot` should work now

Comment: `sudo python` launches system Python, not the one from virtualenv. You can verify that by printing the `sys.path`.

Comment: even though I'm in a virtual environment?